# DataTables warning: table id=example - Ajax error. Using yajra datatables Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I always got this error. And I don't know what is wrong with my code. When I `dd` the data, It shows me the correct one. Does anyone know what should I do about this? Thanks in advance

Error:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

My Ajax code:

```js
@section('scripts')
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = {{ $item->id }};
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            'processing': false,
            'serverSide': true,
            'ajax': "{{route('admin.finances.edit',"+id+")}}",
            'column': [
                {'data': 'id'},
                {'data': 'description'},
                {'data': 'amount'},
                {'data': 'date'}
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
@show
```

Controller:

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    $item = User::where('id', $id)->first();

    $x = \DB::table('finances')
        ->where('finances.user_id', $id)
        ->orderBy('finances.id' ,'DESC')
        ->get()->toArray();

    $details =  Datatables::of($x)->make(true);
    // $results = DataTables::of(Payment::query())->make(true);
    // dd($details);
    return view('admin.pages.finances.show',[
        'mnuname'    => $this->page_title,
        'page_title' => $this->page_title,
        'item'       => $item,
        'details'    => $details,
    ]);
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('finances/{id}', 'FinancesController@edit')
    ->name('admin.finances.edit');
```

when i `dd($details)`

```
JsonResponse {#568 ▼
  #data: "{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":8,"recordsFiltered":8,"data":[{"id":"16","school_id":"1","user_id":"11","amount":"85454","description":"Pinakalatest","date":"2019-11-1 ▶"
  #callback: null
  #encodingOptions: 0
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#567 ▶}
  #content: "{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":8,"recordsFiltered":8,"data":[{"id":"16","school_id":"1","user_id":"11","amount":"85454","description":"Pinakalatest","date":"2019-11-1 ▶"
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 200
  #statusText: "OK"
  #charset: null
  +original: array:5 [▼
    "draw" => 0
    "recordsTotal" => 8
    "recordsFiltered" => 8
    "data" => array:8 [▶]
    "input" => []
  ]
  +exception: null
```

Comment: you can not use js variable `id` to `'ajax': "{{route('admin.finances.edit',"+id+")}}",` directly as it is php code, and js variable can not be bind directly to php

Comment: well it works sir when I use `dd` what should i do to avoid using it?

Comment: add the path without php like - `ajax: '/finances/' + id`.

Comment: instead you can use `'ajax': "{{url('finances')}}/"+id`

Comment: ok sir now i used it. But i got the error in datable. how could i fix it?

Comment: i think you will have to return `$details` instead of `view()`

Comment: but i got many variables to render in my view thats why I put them in array

Comment: I used `'ajax': " '/finances/' + id",` sir @SougataBose But still got the error `ajax error`

Comment: try to put them in `$details`

Comment: can you provide some sample code sir? I a bit confused

Comment: like `$details =  Datatables::of($x)->make(true); $details['mnuname'] = $this->page_title` and so on

Comment: should i put return?

Comment: yes, Of course !

Comment: Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse as array @VibhaChosla

Comment: i used ` return view('admin.pages.finances.show',[
            $details = Datatables::of($x)->make(true),
            $details['mnuname'] = $this->page_title,
            $details['page_title'] = $this->page_title,
            $details['item'] = $this->item
            
        ]);`

Comment: check this https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/7.0/response-with

Comment: How could i return my view with that sir?

Comment: _“well it works sir when I use dd”_ - you should go have a thorough read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming on that first of all, because this is elementary basic knowledge that you seem to be missing so far.

Comment: i dont know really whats wrong with my ajax code

Comment: From documentation: _This occurs when jQuery falls into its error callback handler ..., which will typically occur when the server responds with anything other than a 2xx HTTP status code. For example the server might respond with 404 Not Found ..., or 500 Internal Error..._

Comment: what should I do about it sir? @Styx

Comment: Check the response from the server. https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7#Diagnosis